# Completely positive map is $*$-homomorphism

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a $C^*$ algebra and we have a completely positive contractive map $f \colon A\rightarrow B(H)$ such that $sup_{a,b \in A}\lVert f(ab)-f(a)f(b)\rVert =0$. Can we conclude that $f$ is a $*$-homomorphism?

Comment: As a small add-up. This will still be true is you change completely positive by completely bounded by a (nontrivial) theorem of Haagerup: Every completely bounded homomorphism is equivalent to a $\ast$-homomorphism.

Comment: What is the definition of C.B.homomorphism?

Comment: A multiplicative linear map such that all of its matrix amplifications $id_{\M_k} \otimes \varphi$ are uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions immediately imply that $f$ is an algebra homomorphism.  To show that it preserves adjoints, let $a\in A$ be self-adjoint.  Then $a=a_+-a_-$, where $a_+,a_-$ are positive elements of $A$.  Then $f(a)=f(a_+)-f(a_-)$ is a difference of positive elements (as $f$ is a positive map), hence self-adjoint.  If now $b\in A$ is arbitrary, write $b=b_1+ib_2$, where $b_1,b_2$ are self-adjoint.  Then 
$$f(b)^*=(f(b_1)+if(b_2))^*=f(b_1)-if(b_2)=f(b_1-ib_2)=f(b^*),$$
and therefore $f$ is a $*$-homomorphism.

Indeed, the above work proves the following proposition:

> Let $A,B$ be $C^*$-algebras, and let $f:A\to B$ be a positive linear map.  Then $f$ is $*$-preserving, i.e., $f(a)^*=f(a^*)$ for all $a\in A$.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the sup is take over all $a,b\in A$, then the condition $\sup_{a,b}\|f(ab)-f(a)f(b)\|=0$ is exactly the same as $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b$. Neither contractive not completely positive are relevant in that case. All you need is $f$ to be linear and preserve adjoints.

Comment: I believe the point of the question was to ask whether or not the conditions imply that $f$ is $*$-preserving.

Comment: A (completely) positive map is $*$-preserving.